How to manage relations in DTO with Nestjs and Prisma
I have two models in Prisma: User i UserInfo. I am also using class-validator and class-transformer if it matters.
model User {
  userId         Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  email          String        @unique
  userInfo       UserInfo      @relation(references: [userInfoId], fields: [userInfoId], onDelete: Cascade)
  userInfoId     Int
}

model PersonalInfo {
  personalInfoId Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName      String
  User           User[]
}

They are in a one-to-one relationship, i.e. one user can be associated with one userInfo. How can this connection be mapped in DTO? The only thing that comes to my mind is to add a field of a given type:
export class CreateUserDto {

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsEmail()
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    email: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    userInfo: UserInfo;
}

Is it the correct solution? Or is there another, elegant way?
